# Angular2 + PrimeNG - Dropdown selected value not working properly if Editable is set

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I have an Angular2 application with PrimeNG suite installed.

I'm trying to implement a form with a primeNG dropdown component.

The problem happens when I run the application and I select an element from the listbox.

Instead of shows the value, it shows **[object Object]**

### the problem

[image]

### html component

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="listCustomers_itm" placeholder="Selezionare" formControlName="Customer_itm" [(ngModel)]="Customer_itm" filter="filter" editable="editable"> </p-dropdown>
```

### declarations

```
 /*primeng listBox */
  Customer_itm: SelectItem;
  listCustomers_itm: SelectItem[];
```

### ts code to fill the options:

```
this.mdService.Get_Customer(false).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.listCustomers = data;

        this.listCustomers_itm = [];
        for (let c of this.listCustomers) {
          this.listCustomers_itm.push({ label: (c.code + ' - ' + c.businessName), value: { id: c.idCustomer, name: c.businessName, code: c.code } });
        }

      }
    );
```

If instad of use custom label and value, is use flat values like:

```
this.listCustomers_itm.push({ label: c.code, value:c.businessName });
```

All works properly...

I tried also to implement onChange function:

```
  onCustomerSelect(e)
  {   
    console.log(e);        
  }
```

The ouput in the console when I select an item is:

```
Object { id: 5, name: "Luigino Gatto", code: "5" }
```

I finally discovered that the code works properly if I remove `editable="editable"` attribute, but I need to set it editable...

Thanks to support

Comment: might be because you are instancing  `listCustomers_itm` inside you subscription.

Comment: I moved the command before the subscription but the problem persists

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: Try to log the object that you are pushing it to `listCustomers_itm`

Comment: can you post the Stringified version of `this.listCustomers_itm` after the for loop?

Comment: yes, this is a partial string of values: 

[{"label":"12 - AIEIE BRAZO","value":{"id":12,"name":"AIEIE BRAZO","code":"12"}},{"label":"5 - Luigino Gatto","value":{"id":5,"name":"Luigino Gatto","code":"5"}},{"label":"8 - Luigino Gatto","value":{"id":8,"name":"Luigino Gatto","code":"8"}},{"label":"16 - qqqw","value":{"id":16,"name":"qqqw","code":"16"}},{"label":"20 - RAGIONO MALE","value":{"id":20,"name":"RAGIONO MALE","code":"20"}},{"label":"9 - RAGIONO MOLTO","value":{"id":9,"name":"RAGIONO MOLTO","code":"9"}}

Comment: I just discover that If I remove editable="editable" , all works properly but I need to set this dropdown editable...

Comment: Even I discovered that everything is working fine if i remove `formControlName` property

Comment: This is strange, I tried to remove fromControlName but the problem persists in my case...

Comment: which version of primefaces and angular you are using?

Comment: "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",

"primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.3",

Comment: @Gangadhar can you post the working code ?

Comment: I am having same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pushing individual values in the `value` you can put the entire object in it.

```
this.mdService.Get_Customer(false).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.listCustomers = data;

    this.listCustomers_itm = [];
    for (let c of this.listCustomers) {
      this.listCustomers_itm.push({ label: (c.code + ' - ' + c.businessName), value: c });
    }

  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

from your template it looks like to trying to work with model driven (formcontrolName)
and template driven (ngModel) approach.

which does not make sense.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="listCustomers_itm" placeholder="Selezionare" **formControlName**="Customer_itm" **[(ngModel)]**="Customer_itm" filter="filter" editable="editable"> </p-dropdown>
```

Please select the appropriate why and use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. From what I can tell, when provided with an object as a value, the p-dropdown component will call value.toString().

In order to fix this, I added the following method to the object I wanted in the value field.

```
toString() : string{
  return this.name.toString();
}
```

Just to clarify as to why I'm using name.toString() - Prime likes to work with Typescripts primitive string rather than the wrapper object String.

Comment: Where did you add this?

Comment: I added the toString method to the class I was using with the drop down component. For example, if you have a drop down displaying a list of Car instances, the above code would be placed within the Car class.

Comment: I also did same thing. MyClass has this method. p-dropdown is bound to myClassesItems: SelectItem[]. I push elements like this.. myClassesItems.push({label:myClassObj.name, value:myClassObj }). But still not working...

Comment: Instead, push like myClassesItems.push(myClassObj)

Comment: In my UI, I am creating custom content using pTemplate='item'. I need label and value. How you will read them if I use what you said...

Comment: My bad, I'm writing this on my phone. I think it should be myClassesItems.push({label: myClassObj.name, value: myClassObj})

Comment: I tried.. no use.. myClassesItems.push({label:myClassObj.name, value:myClassObj })

Comment: What error is myClassesItems.push({label:myClassObj.name, value:myClassObj }) causing?

Comment: It doesnot cause any error but it still shows [object Object]. But I see that item selected in my p-dropdown,

Comment: Are you sure the myClassObj has the toString method? [object Object] should be the default toString method of an object. So by adding the toString method to your class, you overwrite it with what you want.

Comment: Yeah I added.. everything works fine if I remove editable property for p-dropdown. But if I add it then it not works...

Comment: In ngAfterViewChecked().. I gave this...  this.newIssuesDropDown.updateEditableLabel();                this.newIssuesDropDown.updateSelectedOption(null);.. it looks good so far. Need to test more...

Comment: The reason why editable doesn't work is that I believe internally, rather than changing the name of the object it creates a new one. This means that the newly created object won't have the correct toString method. You could listen for when the list is updated, check each entry to see if it is instanceof your class if it is not, replace the object with a new instance of your class with the new name value.